# Nested async functions in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, async-await

I have asynchronous functions with firebase and other APIs that depend on each other. So, to start task B has to finish task A.
The async functions are retuning MyResult which can be a success or failure. Now I’m doing it in that way

```
    when(val resullt1 = function1UseCase.getresult1()){
    is MyResult.Success ->{
       when(val result2 = function2UseCase.getResult2()){
            is MyResult.Succes ->{
                //Do something or call another async function 
            }
            is MyResult.Failure ->{
                //Do something or call another async function 
            }
       } 
    }
    is MyResult.Failure ->{
        //Do something or call another async function 
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Because when I have more nested tasks the code doesn’t look very well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple extension. Something like that

```
inline fun <F, R> MyResult<F>.then(function: (F) -> MyResult<R>) = when (this) {
    is MyResult.Succes -> {
        try {
            function(result)
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            MyResult.Failure(your_error_handling_here)
        }
    }
    is MyResult.Failure -> this
}
```

Annnd then it will be like that

```
  when(val result = function1UseCase.getresult1().then { function2UseCase.getResult2() }) {
    is MyResult.Success -> {
    }
    is MyResult.Failure -> {
        //Do something or call another async function 
    }
}
```

You can slightly modify this if you need to have both results at the very end ;)